# Add margin to DIV tags added by PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add margin to this `<div>`:

```
$notification_list .= "
    <div class='FriendRdiv'>
        <a href='main.php?u=".$initiator."'>
            <img src='../img/".$pr."' id='FriendRPP'>
        </a>
        <a id='FriendRfrom'>".$initiator." sent you a friend request</a>
    </div>
    <form class='FriendRForm Rejecat' onsubmit='return false'>
        <input type='submit' value='Reject' id='Reject'>
    </form>         
    <form class='FriendRForm' onsubmit='return false'>
         <input type='submit' value='Accept' id='Accept'>
    </form>";
```

I don't know how many notifications I will get, so I want each `<div>` to have a bigger margin than one before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use style attribute

```
<div class='FriendRdiv' style="margin: 10px;">
```

or you can use css for that  in css file

```
.FriendRdiv{
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again!That was stupid i have never thought about that:D